# Relations typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

How can I create an entity relationship correctly? Using TypeORM and TypeScript, I want to structure the following relationship: I have a 'products' table, another 'price groups' table, and another 'prices' table. Each product has multiple price groups, and for each price group, the product has different prices.I'm still struggling to establish a coherent relationship in TypeORM. I would like users to be able to create a list of products and a list of price groups, with each group managing prices for individual products. When a product is deleted, I want the associated prices to be deleted as well, and when groups are deleted, I want the prices associated with those groups to be removed as well.

```
// Product.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { PriceGroup } from './PriceGroup';

@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => PriceGroup, priceGroup => priceGroup.product, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  priceGroups: PriceGroup[];
}

// PriceGroup.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Product } from './Product';
import { Price } from './Price';

@Entity()
export class PriceGroup {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.priceGroups, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  product: Product;

  @OneToMany(() => Price, price => price.priceGroup, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  prices: Price[];
}

// Price.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { PriceGroup } from './PriceGroup';

@Entity()
export class Price {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  value: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => PriceGroup, priceGroup => priceGroup.prices, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  priceGroup: PriceGroup;
}
```